# Showing "all" companies from sql database in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am updating a C# UICombo box with an option to show all companies from a DB table but I'm having a hard time getting it working. Currently there are two companies showing. And there should be a third option in which you can select "all".

Basically this is the current code, (bedrijf = company, bedrijven = companies, werknemer = eployee.

```
 private void MainForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;
    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    loading = true;

    StartupScreen.setStatus("Bezig met laden van overige instellingen...");
    StartupScreen.NextValue();

    //Alleen de bedrijven tonen waar men recht op heeft
    bedrijven.toonUICombo(cbBedrijf, "", "SELECT Bedrijven.id, naam FROM Bedrijven, Werknemer_Bedrijven WHERE Zichtbaar=1 AND Bedrijven.id=Werknemer_Bedrijven.Bedrijven_id AND Werknemer_id=" + Globals.werknemer.getValue("id"));
    try
    {
        cbBedrijf.SelectedValue = Globals.werknemer.getIntValue("DefaultBedrijfId");
        cbBedrijf.Visible = (cbBedrijf.Items.Count != 1);
        uiTab.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cbBedrijf.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

As you can see there are two tables. Table one (Companies) contains three companies (Company 1,Company 2 and all) with an id/name pair and some other details.

Table two (Employee_Companies) contains id, Employee id, Companies_id and Visibility.

(Please ignore the table names, they are translated from Dutch)

Comment: what do you mean by 1,2 and all? can you put the records that are in your database in your question?

Comment: 1 and 2 are excisting companies

Comment: If "All" is not in you DB then you will have to hardcode the option into your control, if it is in your DB try removing your "where" clause

Comment: Create your SQL dynamically e.g. depending on the selection of your combobox determine what the where clause should be.

Comment: First, use explicit joins. Second, I see no condition on the company, just on the Employee_id. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: If i remove the where clause it will display the 3 options (company 1,2 and all) like 10 times ea ;x

Comment: comboBox.Items.Add("All"); should work but it really depends on what you are trying to achieve and how complex your logic to process the value is going to be

Comment: but how will this get the results from the companies?

Comment: @chris explain to us in Dutch what you are trying to do and I will translate it to English because I think we are getting lost in translation here

Comment: @JeremyC. ik probeer in een combobox een extra optie te maken om alle werknemers weer te geven. Momenteel staan er twee bedrijven in deze combobox. De bedoeling is dat naast deze twee bedrijven er een optie komt om alle werknemers weer te geven. In database één staat bedrijf 1, bedrijf 2 en alle(bedrijf 1 = id 1, bedrijf 2 = id 2 en alle = id 3) Database 1 is afhankelijk van database 2 om de werknemers te kunnen weergeven. In database 2 staat id, werknemer_id, bedrijven_id en zichtbaar. Optie 3 (alle) moet dus bijvoorbeeld de werknemers van bedrijf 1 en bedrijf 2 kunnen weergeven.

Comment: Waarom zit er een optie all in je database? Normaal zou je gewoon de where clause van companyid=? (1 of 2 nu) weglaten als je alles wil laten zien, als je ons wat voorbeelddata zou kunnen geven van in je databank zou het voor iedereen ook veel duidelijker zijn wat je nu juist bedoelt

Comment: probeer eens SELECT Company.id, name FROM Companies, dat zou je normaal al gewoon de 3 companies moeten geven

Comment: For everyone who doesn't speak dutch:
Chris is trying to add an extra option in his combobox that says 'all' which will show all employees from both companies, in his database for companies he has 3 records with primary key (comp1 = 1, comp2 = 2 and ALL = 3) I think this is where the problem lies, the other database is dependant on these foreign keys, but seeing as nobody has a foreign key of 3 (they either have 1 or 2) this probably won't work the way he thinks it will, I'm guessing this is a school asignment and he doesn't know how to dynamically create sql

Comment: Excactly @JeremyC. I understand why it wont work, but what would be an other way to make the "all" option?

Comment: @chris your requirement is depends on the value selected on combobox you need to list the employees..is it correct?

Comment: you could just do a cbcompany.items.add('all') then if selecteditem = 'all' remove your where companyid = x (this is pseudo code I haven't written c# in a while)

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
 try
  {
conn.ConnectionString = "data source=yourserver;User ID=userid;Password=password;initial catalog=database;integrated security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
   conn.Open();

  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("your sql query here", conn);
  SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  cmb_company.Items.Add("3-All");
 while (rd.Read())
  {
   cmb_company.Items.Add(rd.GetValue(0)+"-"+rd.GetValue(1));
  //if you need to show both id and company name

   }
rd.Close();
conn.close();
}
catch(exception ex)
{
}
}
```

Hope this can help.. this will show 3 companies in combo box...
1-comp1, 2- comp2, 3-All
And depends on the value selected you should write the query to show the employees..